# XAML: Bind View to ViewModel from different namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm sure this is a basic question, but I can't figure out how to do this. I have a View in one namespace, and ViewModel in another namespace. How do I bind these two together?

My View is in namespace of MyProject.View. My ViewModel is in namespace of MyProject.ViewModel.

How do I bind this in XAML? I'm doing this in UWP, but I assume this is the same regardless of UWP/WPF/X.Forms.

```
<Page
  x:Class="MyProject.View.MainPage"
  xmlns:vm="using:MyProject.ViewModel"
  DataContext="{Binding MainPageViewModel, Source={StaticResource vm:MainPageViewModel}}"
```

Comment: you need an xmlns for each namespace you want to use.  You can use any name you want.  Just set it equal to the *namespace* of the class only, not the actual name of the class.  You don't need that "using:" in their either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I've made a code sample for your reference:

[image]

```
public class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Name = "Hello UWP!";
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Page
x:Class="AppViewModel.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppViewModel"
xmlns:vm="using:AppViewModel.ViewModel"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel></vm:MainViewModel>
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to do something like that:

```
<Page x:Class="MyProject.View.MainPage" 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels">

    <Page.BindingContext>
        <VM:MainPageViewModel />
    </Page.BindingContext>

    <!-- content here -->

</Page>
```

This will  create a new instance of your `MainPageViewModel` each time you create a new `MainPage`.